# java - create a list from subproperties of another list

Tags: java, java-8

I have three classes defined with their getters and setters as follows by a ORM:

```
class Author {
  Integer id;
  String name;
}

class BookAuthor {
  Integer id_book;
  Author author;
}

class Book {
  String title;
  List<BookAuthor> authors;
}
```

I'd like to create a list of id_author from the class Book.
I've found that a way to do it is using streams. I've tried this:

```
List<Integer> result = authors.stream().map(BookAuthor::getAuthor::getId).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But it does not seem to work.
I can I access the "id" property in the Author class?

EDIT:
maybe a way would be:

```
List<Author> authorList = authors.stream().map(BookAuthor::getAuthor).collect(Collectors.toList());
List<Integer> result = authorList.stream().map(Author::getId).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the `authors` variable is a list (or collection) of BookAuthor, not Author (that what it seems like based on your code).

I think you have the right idea, I just dont think you can chain `::` operators.

So try with lambda:

```
authors.stream().
     map(ba -> ba.getAuthor().getId()).
     collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I'm missing what is ba here

Comment: @Alex Its the instance of BookAuthor. It represents particular element of your stream that you will map. You could write BookAuthor ba if you wanted to, but you dont have to as Java will infer it.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Example {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
     Book book1 = new Book(); book1.authors = new ArrayList<BookAuthor>();
     Author author1 = new Author(); author1.id = 5;
     BookAuthor bookAuthor1 = new BookAuthor(); bookAuthor1.author = author1;
     book1.authors.add(bookAuthor1);
     List<Integer> idList = book1.authors.stream().map(ba -> ba.author.id).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
}
```

Comment: Production classes should of course have constructors, encapsulation, etc

Answer (score 0):

You can't chain method reference like this. But you can use the `map` function twice:

```
authors.stream()
   .map(BookAuthor::getAuthor)
   .map(Author::getId)
   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```